# magento new order send mail not work

Tags: magento-1.9, email, order-email

magento can send new user mail confirmation, newsletter subscription, invoice and shipment success but can't send new order mail and send order email to customer in admin panel.

in database core_email_queue is full of not sent emails

also i did:

```
sudo crontab -u www-data -e
```

and add:

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /home/salar/public_html/cron.sh
```

this is my AOE Scheduler:
[image]

Comment: Not sure what the problem can be, but since you are using Aoe Scheduler consider replacing cron.sh for scheduler_cron.sh, so it would be like: * * * * * /bin/sh /home/salar/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh